# How do we input type value as object in function input parameter?

Tags: function, oop, object, lua

I want to ask about how to compare an object or use an object as parameter input in lua function, I came from java so it's something similar like this

```
public void steal(Person other, double value) { 
    other.balance -= value;
}
```

as we see there is Person object as parameter how do you do that in lua? since it seems every function in lua has no type value like

```
function steal(value)
    self.balance = self.balance - value -- i know it's wrong since it reference to self but i think it something like this
end
```

the value is can be anything since lua is not origin OOP so I don't know how to do it but I've been learning some OOP in lua on interwebs and stuck in this point, how do we input value as object?

Comment: Lua is dynamically typed; variables don't have types, values do. (Also this does not mean that Lua is not OOP; it can be)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the variable?

```
function steal(whatever, value)
    whatever.balance = whatever.balance - value
end
```

Comment: thanks, this works thought it would be hard didn't think could be this way